# Javascript - reading arrays from JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, api

I am working with an API that is returning data in JSON format. An example of a response is this

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "count": 4,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "date": "2013-05-24T09:19:37.964+1000",
    "executedQuery": "cafe",
    "message": "OK",
    "originalQuery": "cafe",
    "results": [{
            "aboutId": "b3ec5ac4096078f89fa4a9f3adcec930a1d4997c7cae30b026d61f8fcbf2013b",
            "categories": [{
                    "id": "35491",
                    "name": "Cafes",
                    "sensitive": false
                }],
            "detailsLink": "http://www.yellowpages.com.au/nsw/mt-colah/bobbin-inn-13830124-listing.html?referredBy=TAPI-jHOsyHrSfHBBlo0IExDjXZZJx6PszwX6",
            "hasExposureProducts": false,
            "id": "13830124",
            "listingType": "Business",
            "name": "Bobbin Inn",
            "primaryAddress": {
                "addressLine": "1 Chase Rd",
                "geoCodeGranularity": "PROPERTY",
                "latitude": "-33.678276",
                "longitude": "151.112964",
                "mappable": true,
                "postcode": "2079",
                "state": "NSW",
                "suburb": "Mt Colah",
                "type": "PHYSICAL"
            },
            "primaryContacts": [{
                    "type": "PHONE",
                    "value": "(02) 9457 7170"
                }],
            "pureMobileBusiness": false,
…
```

From what i can tell there is a number of arrays in this response. I am failing however to parse this data on a create method

here is my code (this is working for this field i have defined but ... see below)

```
 for (var i in p) {
     str += blocka + uibare + p.executedQuery + " (" + p.executedQuery+ ")</div></div>";
     str += blockb + uibarc + p.executedQuery + "</div></div>";
     str += blockc + uibare + p.executedQuery + "</div></div>";
     str += blockd + uibarc + p.executedQuery + "</div></div>";
     str += blocke + uibare + p.executedQuery + "</div></div>";
      }
```

This is working, because executedQuery is not part of the array. However if i want to get for example the "name" that appears to be part of the results array? Or am i reading it wrong?

so i tried

```
str += blockb + uibarc + p.results[i].name + "</div></div>";
```

and it won't pull any data.

Comment: this json is not correct at all, doesn't even have a closing bracket

Comment: Did you try `console.log(jons)` your json? What's the ouput? Is it a string or an object? JSON validator => http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: So what is `p`? Is it the `JSON.parse`d object representing your string? Why don't you use the `i` property?

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 1:
...bileBusiness":false,
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got 'EOF'

Comment: Have you tried `p["results"][i]["name"]`. Also have you tried a simple iterating for loop (rather than a for-each) with `i<p.results.length`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array that contains a single object of keys and values.

Try `result[0]["name"]`.

More suitable to your request:

```
str += blockb + uibarc + p.results[0]["name"] + "</div></div>";
```

Comment: The API guys are positive they spit it back in JSON and thats what it spits out (although its an excerpt)

Comment: And yep i've validated it just then. It says valid JSON response (when i use the URL, i'd like to paste it here but it has my private API key)

Comment: p is my function, so $.getJSON("http://api.sensis.com.au/ob-20110511/test/search?key=<private>&query=cafe&location=mountcolah&postcode=2079", function(p) {

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. What I suggested wasn't helpful? it doesn't work when accessing the array with a second indexer (*[..]*) to get the name?

Comment: Hi Adam, i was responding to some others, sorry :( I am going to try your solution now :)